# Display all checked out files in StarTeam 2005R2

Tags: starteam

Is there a way to display all checked out files across multiple projects in StarTeam 2005R2?

Comment: I'm not sure. But if not you can use the Starteam SDK (which is very good actually) to access the repository to collect all the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[StarTeam SDK](http://techpubs.borland.com/starteam/2005r2/en/sdk/api/index.html)** for that - there are some examples that show you
how to iterate all the projects and their views.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you would make use of the Class CheckoutManager to view all checked out files across a time period and project range.